# How to make "enter" button execute when hover in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make Dos- like menu. I have event that hovers elements with arrow keys. How to make "enter" executing so going to another html document?
So generally how to make this working like in DOS? ;)

This is html, js and css:

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".hoverlist li");

    document.addEventListener("keydown",handler);


    function handler(e){
        console.log(e.which);
            active.classList.remove("hover");
        if (e.which == 40){
            active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
        }else if (e.which == 38){
            active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
        }else{
            active = e.target;
        }
            active.classList.add("hover");
    }
```

```css
input.button {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

.hoverlist {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hoverlist li.hover {
  background-color: #00CECD;
  color: black;
}

body {
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "hoverlist">
                    <li class = "hover"><form action="index.html">
                        <input class= "button"    type="submit" value="/home       | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></li>
                    <li><form action="about.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/about me   | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></li>
                    <li><form action="projects.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/projects   | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></li>
                    <li><form action="experience.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/experience | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></li>
                    <li><form action="projects.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/contact me | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: I can't exactly tell what pressing enter is supposed to do in your context. You probably want the hover to do the action directly, rather then really faking a key press event.

Comment: I mean when <li> element is hovered and i press enter then it should perform action so for example first <li> is hovered I press enter and then action is to go to index.html as its defined in this element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll expand on Steven's answer here, to point some problems you have:

3. Always attach events to the smallest element they are relevant to, not the entire document.
4. You probably don't want to redirect on hover, since as soon as the page loads you will probably trigger a hover event mistakenly and redirect.
5. You're not closing your forms?

I fixed the code like you wanted below, except on `hover` you don't submit but rather set the active properly. You could of course run submit on `e.target.parentNode` instead of setting the `active` element, but I think this behavior is a bit more intuitive.

```js
var active = document.querySelector(".hover") || document.querySelector(".hoverlist li");

    var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var len = lis.length;
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        lis[i].addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) {
          active.classList.remove("hover");
          active=e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
          active.classList.add("hover");
          e.target.parentNode.submit()
        });
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e){
        active.classList.remove("hover");
        if (e.which == 40){
            active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
        }else if (e.which == 38){
            active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
        }else{
            active = e.target;
        }
        active.classList.add("hover");
   });
```

```css
input.button {
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

.hoverlist {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.hover {
  background-color: #00CECD;
  color: black;
}

body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "hoverlist">
                    <li class='hover'><form action="index.html">
                        <input class= "button"    type="submit" value="/home       | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></form></li>
                    <li><form action="about.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/about me   | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></form></li>
                    <li><form action="projects.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/projects   | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></form></li>
                    <li><form action="experience.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/experience | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></form></li>
                    <li><form action="projects.html">
                        <input class= "button" type="submit" value="/contact me | 24 kb | 20.09.17" /></form></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: @KrisW I used Jquery by mistake - fixed it to pure JS now, so it suits you better. Note there are quite a few fixes to your code.

Comment: @KrisW I wish you told me I missed you're entire keyboard handler! You were correct to use `hover` as a class rather than an attribute. I removed what I erroneously thought was a problem, with the final minimal code.

Comment: thanks for effort. It works better than what i wrote when it comes to hover and i will use it, but it still doesn't have the function that i'm looking for. First answer by user8320550 too, I was wrong. Maybe I don't explain it clearly enough. This is how it works now https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MEJdyo I want hovered <li> on enter to perform action (for example go to about.html). I have tried many different things, none of them works. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @KrisW Just add in the `mouseover` whatever you want. For example submit the form - which I think is bad, but you can if you want. I changed the code so it does this (the line that has `submit()`).

Comment: my reputation is low so i you dont see me votes yet ;) and i dont see the option accept so it is probably the same case.

Answer (score 2):

You could run .submit() when the user hovers the element.

```
   function handler(e){
        console.log(e.which);
            active.classList.remove("hover");
        if (e.which == 40){
            active = active.nextElementSibling || active;
        }else if (e.which == 38){
            active = active.previousElementSibling || active;
        }else{
            active = e.target;
        }
            active.classList.add("hover");
    }
```

Just use `document.querySelector(".form").submit()` when the user presses enter.

Comment: No problem, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

With the arrow keys, you are focusing list items.
Maybe if you try to focus the button inside, then enter will submit the form ...
So maybe try something like this at the end of your handler?

```
active.querySelector('.button').focus();
```